# Remove group from pandas df if at least one group member consistently meets condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['peter', 'peter', 'peter', 'peter', 'peter', 'peter', 'david', 'david', 'david', 'david', 'david', 'david'], 
     'class': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
     'value': [2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 4, 7, 0, 9, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

name    class   value
peter   A       2
peter   B       0
peter   A       3
peter   B       5
peter   A       0
peter   B       0
david   A       4
david   B       7
david   C       0
david   A       9
david   B       1
david   C       0
```

I would like to group this dataframe by `name` and `class` and delete a whole `name` group if at least one group member constantly equals 0. In the example above, all `C`'s of the `david` group equal 0. For that reason, I would like to *remove* the `david` group and *keep* the `peter` group, see desired output below. Any advice on how to achieve this?

```
name    class   value
peter   A       2
peter   B       0
peter   A       3
peter   B       5
peter   A       0
peter   B       0
```

Comment: Can you add an 'expected output' to your post? it would be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) to get the names which meet the condition to filter out and then boolean mask like:

```
names = df.groupby(["name", "class"]).filter(lambda g: g.value.eq(0).all())["name"]
df[~df["name"].isin(names)]

    name class  value
0  peter     A      2
1  peter     B      0
2  peter     A      3
3  peter     B      5
4  peter     A      0
5  peter     B      0
```

Or just in one command:

```
df[
    ~df["name"].isin(
        df.groupby(["name", "class"]).filter(lambda g: g.value.eq(0).all())["name"]
    )
]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
# is value zero?
df['is_zero'] = df['value'] == 0

# Check combination of name and class which has all zeros
all_zeros = df.groupby(['name', 'class'], as_index=False)['is_zero'].all()

# filter the names for all such combinations
names = all_zeros.loc[all_zeros['is_zero'], 'name']

# Query the dataframe to exclude such names
result = df.query('name not in @names')
```

Result

```
    name class  value  is_zero
0  peter     A      2    False
1  peter     B      0     True
2  peter     A      3    False
3  peter     B      5    False
4  peter     A      0     True
5  peter     B      0     True
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering the filter, one liner:

```
output = (
    df.groupby('name').filter(
        lambda x: x.groupby('class')['value'].filter(
            lambda y: y.eq(0).all()
        ).all()
    )
)
```

Output:

```
    name class  value
0  peter     A      2
1  peter     B      0
2  peter     A      3
3  peter     B      5
4  peter     A      0
5  peter     B      0
```